# OpenGL: glVertexAttribFormat.attribindex vs GLSL vertex shader location

Tags: c++, opengl

Does the `attribindex` in [`glVertexAttribFormat`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml) correspond with the layout location in my GLSL vertex shader?

i.e. if I write

```
glVertexAttribFormat(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(Vertex, position));
```

That `0` would correspond with this line in my shader?

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.  Otherwise without a `location` specifier you have to query the attribute location via `glGetAttribLocation()` after program linking or set it before program linking via `glBindAttribLocation()`.

Comment: Perfect. I was pretty sure that was the case, but couldn't find anywhere that explicitly said it.